# SAML интеграция с ЕСИА, формирование сигнатуры запроса

Tags: java, x509, saml

Возможно кому-то приходилось проводить интеграцию с данным сервисом [ЕСИА](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8). Вопрос возникает в формировании сигнатуры к запросу, т.к. используется протокол `SSO SAML`: после формирования запроса на аутентификацию требуется поместить в `GET-запрос` ряд параметров: `SamlAuth`, `AlgSig`, `relayState` и `Signature`.

- Вопрос 1: Что такое `relayState` и как оно формируется?
- Вопрос 2: Как правильно сформировать сигнатуру(подпись `AuthRequest` запроса) закрытым ключом? С помощью `java.security.Signature` подписываю `byte[]` из строки запроса(уже приведенной к `base64`), таким образом получаю новый `byte[]` (сигнатура, подпись). Следующим шагом требуется перегнать подпись в строку и поместить параметром в Get-запрос, но проблема возникает в кодирование: следует ли `byte[]` подписи изначально кодировать в `base64`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Рекомендую копать в сторону spring-saml, у меня оно отлично привинтилось.
Приложу свой конфиг saml-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">

<bean id="samlFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <security:filter-chain-map request-matcher="ant">
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/user/saml/login/**" filters="samlEntryPoint"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/user/saml/authnrequestresponselistener/**"
                               filters="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter"/>
    </security:filter-chain-map>
</bean>

<!-- Handler deciding where to redirect user after successful login -->
<bean id="successRedirectHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/user/login/esia/"/>
</bean>

<!-- Register authentication manager with SAML provider -->
<!--<security:authentication-manager alias="samlAuthenticationManager">-->
    <!--<security:authentication-provider ref="samlAuthenticationProvider"/>-->
<!--</security:authentication-manager>-->

<bean id="samlAuthenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <!-- SAML Authentication Provider responsible for validating of received SAML messages -->
            <bean id="samlAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider">
                <!-- OPTIONAL property: can be used to store/load user data after login -->
                <!--<property name="userDetails" ref="samlUserDetailsService" />-->
            </bean>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<!-- Logger for SAML messages and events -->
<bean id="samlLogger" class="org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger">
    <property name="logMessages" value="true"/>
</bean>

<!-- Central storage of cryptographic keys -->
<bean id="keyManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager">
    <constructor-arg value="classpath:esia/esia.jks"/>
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="******"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="entryKey" value="******"/>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="someValue"/>
</bean>

<!-- Entry point to initialize authentication, default values taken from properties file -->
<bean id="samlEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint">
    <property name="defaultProfileOptions">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileOptions">
            <property name="includeScoping" value="false"/>
            <property name="binding" value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Filter automatically generates default SP metadata -->
<bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<!-- IDP Metadata configuration - paths to metadata of IDPs in circle of trust is here -->
<!-- Do no forget to call iniitalize method on providers -->
<bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider">
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <value type="java.io.File">classpath:esia/esia_edu_metadata.xml</value>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider">
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <value type="java.io.File">classpath:esia/esia_prod_metadata.xml</value>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider">
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <value type="java.io.File">classpath:esia/shibboleth.xml</value>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
    <!-- Set provider edu or prod -->
    <property name="hostedSPName" value="hostname.ru"/>
</bean>

<!-- Provider of default SAML Context -->
<bean id="contextProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderImpl"/>

<!-- Processing filter for WebSSO profile messages -->
<bean id="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <value type="java.lang.String">/user/saml/authnrequestresponselistener</value>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="samlAuthenticationManager"/>
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successRedirectHandler"/>
</bean>

<!-- Class loading incoming SAML messages from httpRequest stream -->
<bean id="processor" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="redirectBinding"/>
            <ref bean="postBinding"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<!-- SAML 2.0 WebSSO Assertion Consumer -->
<bean id="webSSOprofileConsumer" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl"/>

<!-- SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key WebSSO Assertion Consumer -->
<bean id="hokWebSSOprofileConsumer" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl"/>

<!-- SAML 2.0 Web SSO profile -->
<bean id="webSSOprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileImpl"/>

<!-- SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key Web SSO profile -->
<bean id="hokWebSSOProfile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl"/>

<!-- SAML 2.0 ECP profile -->
<bean id="ecpprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileECPImpl"/>

<!-- Bindings, encoders and decoders used for creating and parsing messages -->
<bean id="redirectBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding">
    <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
</bean>

<bean id="postBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPostBinding">
    <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="velocityEngine"/>
</bean>

<!-- Initialization of OpenSAML library-->
<bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLBootstrap"/>

<!-- Initialization of the velocity engine -->
<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.security.saml.util.VelocityFactory"
      factory-method="getEngine"/>

<!-- XML parser pool needed for OpenSAML parsing -->
<bean id="parserPool" class="org.opensaml.xml.parse.StaticBasicParserPool" init-method="initialize"/>
<bean id="parserPoolHolder" class="org.springframework.security.saml.parser.ParserPoolHolder"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

relayState - можно не указывать.
Signature в ЕСИА надо указать '-' примерно так на Ruby:

```
params[:SAMLRequest]= Base64.strict_encode64(Zlib::Deflate.deflate(signed_request, 9)[2..-5])
params[:Signature]  = '-'
params[:SigAlg]     = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1'
```

Подписание дело тонкое: ищите как подписываются xml, куда вставляются блоки, ds:Signature, каноникализация и пр.

Можете посмотреть информацию здесь: http://esia.pro

Comment: Но ведь наличие сигнатуры прописано в методичке ЕСИА, да и relayState вроде как является "уникальным идентификатором" сессии входа, если я ничего не путаю

Comment: Я вам говорю как оно на практике 'чтоб работало'. Добейтесь чтоб заработало - потом будете наводить марафет :)

Answer (score 2):

Исходя из нашего опыта работы могу добавить:

1. relayState - это уникальный идентификатор сессии в интегрируемом приложении, в результате авторизации ЕСИА вернет его обратно и приложение сможет его связать с запросом
2. Порядок формировании подписи:

1) выполняется deflate строки запроса - получается byte

2) выполняется подпись полученного на шаге 1 - получается byte

3) выполняется кодирование в base64 полученного на шаге 2

В дополнение могу порекомендовать посмотреть не только готовое решение, упомянутое **Samoilenko Yuri**, но и [ESIA-Bridge](http://identityblitz.ru/products/esia-bridge/).